# How to generate operation documentation at run time?

Tags: asp.net, swagger-ui, swashbuckle

Can you set Swashbuckle documentation for an Operation at runtime?

Example: document list of values that are allowed, which is based on an internal dictionary but could also be based on configuration.

What does not solve the problem:

- Use XML documentation: sets documentation from the XML comments in code. This is static instead of dynamic.
- Set global description using the AddSwaggerGen method. This is dynamic, but at the wrong level.

Answer (score 0):

Using an ISchemaFilter you can do some crazy documentation.

Here is an example:

https://github.com/heldersepu/csharp-proj/blob/master/WebApi_MyGet/WebApi_MyGet/App_Start/SwaggerConfig.cs#L277